# null pointer exception at prepared statement

Tags: java, jsp

i am getting a null pointer exception.i don't know the reason why am i getting it? This is the sentence where i am getting Exception "prest = conn.preparedstatemt(sql)".

```
conn = DBHandler.getDBConnection();
String nextOccid = "";
sql = "select nextOccId from ColdStorage.master_ids";
prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs5 = prest.executeQuery();
while (rs5.next()) {
    nextOccid = rs5.getString("nextOccId");
}
```

i have a dbhandler file which has the connection string whose code i have attached here.

```
public static Connection getDBConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
Connection conn = null;
String strUserID, strUserPwd, strURL = null;
try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        strUserID = "root";
        strUserPwd = "";
        strURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ColdStorage? zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(strURL, strUserID, strUserPwd);
```

Comment: At what line you are getting the exception? Also don't just tell the line number, please specify exactly which line. A full stacktrace will be really useful

Comment: Looks like `conn` is null (which can happen when the DriverManager could not get a connection).

Comment: @Thilo how can i rectify this?

Comment: You get null for the connection if connection details are incorrect. check your url, username and password

Comment: check for `null` and throw a SQLException("failed to get connection"). Then find out why this happened.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar i am getting exception at prest = conn.preparedstatemt(sql)

Comment: Did you include the MySql driver for the database on the classpath?

Comment: Then definitely you are getting the null connection. If the parameters are correct, check whether you have put jdbc driver jar file in classpath.

Comment: u guys were rite. its not getting the connection. i guess i am not including the dbhandler file correctly. can that be the problem??

Comment: try debugging to track null value.

Comment: thanks @SachinVerma .. got the problem. rectified it too.. thank guys..

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
strURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ColdStorage? zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
```

Remove the space in the URL. Failing that, double check if it is the correct URL and your username/password, as well as make sure you have the mysql connector JAR in your included libraries.

Comment: i have included all the required libraries.n checked the url too. i guess i am not including the dbhandler file correctly. can that be the problem??

Comment: Did you try the url without the space yet? Like `strURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ColdStorage?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";`? If so go to your project, open build path, and point to your mysql connector JAR if you haven't yet.